# How do I use onClickListener to count the number of times a button is pressed?

Tags: android, button

I want to count how many times a button (which are created dynamically) is pressed.
Actually, the problem is that I cannot find a way to return anything out of onclicklistener due to the fact that onClick is Void and onclicklistener can only return as view.

```
public  View.OnClickListener evenbutton(final Button inputbutton,
                                        final LinearLayout layout,
                                        final Button[] wholebutton,
                                        final int count){
    return new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
          //stuff
        }
    }
};
```

So, now I cannot count or return anything else inside onClick.

How can I count or reach anything outside of onclicklistener when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increment a static field declared in your class.

Answer (score 4):

You can call a function that counts the click, like:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    countClick();
}
```

And then declare your function

```
public void countClick(){
    myClickCount++;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Assign a global int i.And keep on incrementing it, every time you click the button.

replace "stuff" with

i=i+1;

Comment: Won't work, as i would need to be final to be used within the inner class. And obviously it' can't be. @oriolpons solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SharedPreferences for this purposes. Every time you click on button you can read the preference you have, change it and save. Moreover, it is one of proposed ways for data storage in documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref