# how to add counter in android studio to quit an application

Tags: android, counter, exit

I am getting an error when I set the counter to subtract and close the application. I get an error "cannot assign value to final variable counter". If the user logins in 3 times with no success quit the application.

```
        final int counter = 3;

        //Set the OKButton to accept onClick
        OKButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            //once onClick is initalized it takes user to page menu
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //display text that was inputed for userText and passText
                user = userText.getText().toString();
                pass = passText.getText().toString();

                //create if loop which checks if user and pass equals the credentials
                if (user.equals("pshivam") && pass.equals("Bway.857661")) {

                    //display toast access welcome
                    String welcome = "Access Granted.";

                    //Create a Toast to display the welcome string in the MainActivity.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, welcome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setContentView(R.layout.account_main);
                }
                //create else if loop which checks if user or pass does not equals the credentials
                else if (!user.equals("pshivam") || !pass.equals("Bway.857661")){

                    //displays previous entry
                    userText.setText(user);
                    passText.setText(pass);

                    //allows user to re-enter credentials.
                    user = userText.getText().toString();
                    pass = passText.getText().toString();


                    //display toast access fail
                    String fail = "Access Denied! Please Try again.";
                    //Create a Toast to display the fail string in the MainActivity.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counter--;
                    if(counter == 0){
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't change the value of final variables

Comment: how do I change it? use a regular int?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
OKButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int counter = 3;
            @Override
            //once onClick is initalized it takes user to page menu
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

You can also call a function from inside `onClick` which will decrement the variable, or use a static field declared in your class

This [How to increment a Counter inside an OnClick View Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112791/how-to-increment-a-counter-inside-an-onclick-view-event) and [How do I use onClickListener to count the number of times a button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386712/how-do-i-use-onclicklistener-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-button-is-pressed) might help.

Edit:

What you are doing in else part doesn't make sense. You are setting text for `userText` and `passText` that you just got using getText() from these. Then you are storing these same values to `user` and `pass`. But you aren't using these variables anywhere and they get new values when `onClick` is called again. Why not keep it simple :

```
                else {

                    //display toast access fail
                    String fail = "Access Denied! Please Try again.";
                    //Create a Toast to display the fail string in the MainActivity.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counter--;
                    if(counter == 0){
                        finish();
                    }
                }
```